# What is the type denoted by a decltype-specifier whose expression is a member of a temporary object of class-type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, value-categories

Say we have the following declaration:

```
struct S {
  int a;
};
```

What is the type denoted by the following *simple-type-specifier*?
Is it `int` or `int&&`?

```
decltype(S{}.a)
```

(This question is intended to address C++17,
but answers addressing other versions of the standard are also appreciated.)

Comment: Given the value-categories tag, I feel it's apt to mention that despite not being `int&&`, it _will_ still bind to an `int&&` because it's an xvalue.

Comment: @chris Good suggestion. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: You can mostly ask to your compiler [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbd06291787a0e86).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `int`.
Per [[dcl.type.simple]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as
>   follows:
>
> - [...]
> - otherwise, if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or **an unparenthesized class member access**, `decltype(e)` is **the type of
>     the entity named by `e`**. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names
>     a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - [...]

The entity named by `S{}.a` is `a`, which is of type `int`.
Therefore, `decltype(S{}.a)` denotes the type `int`.
(Thanks to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166005/what-is-the-type-denoted-by-a-decltype-specifier-whose-expression-is-a-member-of/56166006?noredirect=1#comment98963494_56166006) for pointing this out!)

---

As mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166005/what-is-the-type-denoted-by-a-decltype-specifier-whose-expression-is-a-member-of?noredirect=1#comment98959015_56166005), although the type denoted by `decltype(S{}.a)` is `int`, `S{}.a` is an xvalue and can be bound to `int&&` as in:

```
int&& rv = S{}.a;
```

Comment: The expr.ref quote isn't relevant - it's talking about the type of the full expression, but we just want the type of the entity `a`.

Comment: @Barry Thank you for pointing this out! Apparently I was overlooking "the entity named by `e`." I have updated my answer to reflect that.